Using named ranges in charts without typing their name?
Is there any way in Excel to use named ranges in charts without typing their name? Something like the "Paste Name" window in formulas (available by pressing the F3 key)?


You can actually do that. You need to select the Chart, then click on Chart Design from the ribbon, Select Data --> Click on series fields --> Now hit backspace until ! this and press F3 to enter the desired named ranges. --> Press OK

@MayukhBhattacharya Sounds interesting. Can you explain a bit more please? When I press F3, nothing shows up.

Alright, refer this post answer, I have posted this sometime back. This should help you to understand Excel - creating a chart using column data as x axis labels - how to set date intervals to yearly, rather than daily?
